# How to create record class with default constructor

Tags: class, f#, constructor, struct

structures got default constructors like if I do

```
type tagONEDEV_FlowRec =
    struct
        .......
    end
```

I can do `new DeviceModel.tagONEDEV_FlowRec()` but it doesn't work with this :

```
let (<++|) device bytes size =
    let unmanagedPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size : int)
    Marshal.Copy( (bytes : byte array), 0, unmanagedPtr, size)
    Marshal.PtrToStructure(unmanagedPtr, (device : obj)) // Here
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPtr)
```

I need a record class here alike

```
[<type:StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)>]
type tagONEDEV_FlowRec = { 
    mutable ....;}
```

or

```
type tagONEDEV_FlowRec =
    class
        .......
    end
```

but there is no default constructor here and structures is very big to zero init them manually, so how can I use such classes with default constructors ?

If I will not find the solution I think that will be faster for me to recode this part on C# or even on VB.NET. Sounds alike crutch-solution but looking like I can't dial with F# OOP part yet.

an addition: the thing I don't want to type is :

```
               {TimeRec     = 0; 
                Num         = 0us;
                FlagErr     = 0us;
                C6          = 0.0;
                C2H6        = 0.0;
                C3H8        = 0.0;
                CH4         = 0.0;
                CO2         = 0.0;
                iC4H10      = 0.0;
                iC5H12      = 0.0;
                neoC5H12    = 0.0;
                N2          = 0.0;
                nC5H12      = 0.0;
                O2          = 0.0;
                nC4H10      = 0.0;
                He          = 0.0;
                H2          = 0.0;
                H2O         = 0.0;
                id          = 0us; }
```

<- that is what I want to have by default, because I've got much lager structures then this and writing such constuctors is wicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as jpalmer tried to explain a record has to be initialized with the parameters. I think you should try to use

```
type MyStruct =
    struct
        val mutable myInt : int
        val mutable myString : string
    end
```

see here: [MSDN Docs Explicit Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469494%28VS.100%29.aspx)

yeah I know there are more lines of code and an additional "struct", "end" and some "val"s but is this really this hard? If you are using 1000 properties on your type you should rethink your code anyhow.

Comment: If I have a big structure or record type it must not mean I need to recode it. When I'm using struct instead of class I've got error message on PtrToStructure : This structure should not be a class value.Parameter name: structure. That's why I'm looking for default constructor for class instead of using structure.

Comment: check question update, I descripted what did I called "really this hard"

Comment: sorry but first point in your question you create a struct so I choose to take this one. You just cannot expect us to run your partial code to find every caveat. I read your describition as the problem being with the "defaultconstructor" not with the struct (after seeing your complain on the first answer). As you can see your solution is basically the same (only you have to add the DefaultValue-Attrib) - and I guess you took the *solution* from the link I provided - right? - Sorry if this didn't help you as expected.

Comment: Yes, I found solution in the provided link. In your example you are using struct which is not allowed for me to use because of PtrToStructure. The line new() = {} makes what I wanted to have, DefaultValue allows me to not write big constructor code.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like I found a working trick :

```
[<type:StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)>]
type tagONEDEV_FlowRec =
    class
        [<DefaultValue>] val RecTime         : int;
        [<DefaultValue>] val FlowTime        : int;
        [<DefaultValue>] val AbsPress        : single;
        [<DefaultValue>] val T               : single;
        [<DefaultValue>] val DP_V_FlowRate   : single;
        [<DefaultValue>] val Volume          : double;
        [<DefaultValue>] val Energy          : double;
        [<DefaultValue>] val id              : UInt16;
        new() = {} 
    end
```

Comment: its probably less effort to just do something like `let inline z:'t = fun _ -> LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero` then you can write `val value : int = z()` which will save some typing

Comment: @jpalmer [<DefaultValue>] is looking like better for me, I don't type it, I copypaste it ...

Answer (score 4):

If you for some reason really do want to initialize a record, as John said, there are 
"hackish solution"s.

Here is mine: (I agree with if you have to do this, you probably are doing it wrong, but i assure you mine really helped for what i was doing :).

```
let rec unsafeDefaultValues (x:System.Type) = 
  if x.IsValueType then System.Activator.CreateInstance(x)
  else if (Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsRecord x) then
    let cntr = x.GetConstructors() |> Array.pick Some
    let values = 
      cntr.GetParameters()
      |> Array.map (fun p -> unsafeDefaultValues p.ParameterType)
    cntr.Invoke(values)
  else if (Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsTuple(x)) then
    let tupleValues = 
      Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.GetTupleElements(x)
      |> Array.map (unsafeDefaultValues)
    Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.MakeTuple(tupleValues, x)
  else if (x.IsArray) then
    box (System.Array.CreateInstance(x.GetElementType(), 0))
  else
    null

let unsafeDefaultValuesFor<'a> = unsafeDefaultValues typeof<'a> :?> 'a
```

End here is how you would use it:

```
type A = {
  String : string
  Int : int
  StringOption : string Option
}

type B = {
  String : string
  Int : int
  A : A  
}

unsafeDefaultValuesFor<B>
```

And the result would look like this:
{String = null; Int = 0; A = {String = null; Int = 0; StringOption = null;};}

Comment: For a moment I already don't need it but I really like your solution!

Comment: Case for `Union` is missing. Added it by next funcs: `Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases` then `Reflection.FSharpValue.MakeUnion`. Does not support `Union` with fields though, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334493/2346621 to add the support (did not try latter yet by myself)

Answer (score 3):

In F# you can put a default constructor using implicit syntax like

```
type type(arg1,arg2) =
   let v1 = arg1
   let v2 = arg2
   ....
```

I think you are using `record` in a way which is a bit odd, in F# a record is similar to a tuple with named members - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx

**EDIT**

So the question is basically can you have a constructor which zeroes a record type - answer no.  In this case I think the best answer is to switch from a record to a struct / class so that you can get the behaviour you want.

One hackish solution that I thought of was to use `System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance` which can sometimes help with things like this, but the compiler provides no default constructor so it doesn't work

Comment: no, it's to much work. I need really default nulled constructor without parameters.

Comment: I've got this class with some structure arrays inside and many members / values. I don't want to write 1000 lines of code constructor for it.

Comment: this won't have the default constructer he wants but this is easily changed by adding a `new() = ...` member

Comment: @Veronica - you will have to switch from records to classes / structs see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Use CLIMutable to declare a record with an implicit default constructor.

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type MyRecord = { MyField: int }
```

In order to prevent code drift, I recommend the following style in favor of the above.

```
type [<CLIMutable>] MyRecord = { MyField: int }
```

"Code drift" is the tendency for stuff like attributes to drift away from the code element for which it was originally intended, without anyone noticing it. With the second style, it is more unlikely that the attribute will drift away from the declaration due to carelessness while editing.