# How do I get a discriminated union case from a string?

Tags: reflection, f#, discriminated-union

I have a discriminated union and I want to select a case based on a string (which is read from a JSON file). This is easy to do:

```
type MyDU = A | B
let str = "B"
let myDU : MyDU =
    match str with
    | "A" -> MyDU.A
    | "B" -> MyDU.B
    | _ -> failwith "whatever"
// val myDU : MyDU = B
```

However, sometimes there are many cases, which would require a lot of typing.

The `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` library allows me to get a `UnionCaseInfo` 
 object:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
let myDUInfo : UnionCaseInfo =
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<MyDU>)
    |> Array.find (fun x -> x.Name = str)
// val myDUInfo : UnionCaseInfo = MyDU.B
```

I would like to convert `myDUInfo` into a union case so as to get the same result as the code above relying on `match`, but without having to type the strings corresponding to all the cases.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

To instantiate a union case, use the [`FSharpValue.MakeUnion` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/fsharpvalue.makeunion-method-%5Bfsharp%5D). Here is a function that will instantiate a union case given its name:

```
let instantiate<'t> name =
    Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases( typeof<'t> )
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun uc -> uc.Name = name)
    |> Option.map (fun uc -> Reflection.FSharpValue.MakeUnion( uc, [||] ) :?> 't)
```

Usage:

```
> type T = A | B | C    
> instantiate<T> "A"

val it : T option = Some A
```

NOTE: this function assumes, but does not make sure, that the union case has no arguments. If you give it a case with arguments, it will crash:

```
> type T = A of int | B | C
> instantiate<T> "A"

System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at FSI_0002.instantiate@5.Invoke(UnionCaseInfo uc) in c:\o\a.fsx:line 5
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.OptionModule.Map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2 mapping, FSharpOption`1 option)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0006>.$FSI_0006.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

I leave resolution of this problem as an exercise for the reader (hint: use the [`UnionCase.GetFields` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/unioncaseinfo.getfields-method-%5bfsharp%5d)).